# Trying to dynamically set .find() parameters from client input - mongodb:Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

I am trying to use data from the client, which they would type into an input box. The idea is to use this for finding in my database to pull the data with the same username. on my Mongo DB:Atlas collection.

So its to use it like this to get the names from the database, **.find({"username": request.body})**

However, I keep getting the error **"CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ username: '' }" (type Object) at path "username" for model "Db1"** on my terminal.

But when I try to hard code it onto the .find({"username": "name"), it works fine. Does anyone have any ideas?

````
**Javascript app**
async function pullData () {
let clientQ = document.querySelector('#userDB').value;

let entry = {
   'username':clientQ
};

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
  body: JSON.stringify(entry)
};

const getData = await fetch('/database', options);
 const request = await getData.json();
 console.log(request);

};
```
-----------------------------------------------------
**Node Server**
app.post('/database', (request,response) => {
const info = request.body;
postModel.find({"username": info}, (error,data) => {
  if(error){
      console.log(error);
     } else {
      response.json(data);
     }
   });

});

----------------------------------------------
***client side DB***
async function pullData () {
let clientQ = document.querySelector('#userDB').value;

let entry = {
   'username':clientQ
};

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
  body: JSON.stringify(entry)
};

const getData = await fetch('/database', options);
 const request = await getData.json();
 console.log(request);
````

Comment: Are you getting the body in the node server? Also can you please add HTML content also

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're passing the object `{username : "value"}` to the find method. You need to pass the string.

```
app.post('/database', (request,response) => {
  
  const info = request.body; // object {username : "value"}
  const username = info.username; // the string to search by username
  postModel.find({"username": username}, (error,data) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        response.json(data);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful, you can upvote or mark it as accepted :)